# Reledmac for Arabic edition, problem with critical apparatus

Tags: loops, arabic, reledmac

I'm doing an edition of an Arabic text in Reledmac. One of the problems I'm facing is that for some reason, the second of the notes in the critical apparatus is never given a line number. The following example works (in that it generates a printable pdf), but (1) it always gives the second critical note 0 (it should be 1), and (2) it returns two error warnings: (2a) "Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup (]...)" and (2b) "File ended while scanning use of \@ref. (\beginnumbering ...)". I'd be grateful for any guidance on this.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{libertineotf}
\usepackage[noend,nofamiliar,noeledsec,series={A}]{reledmac}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Amiri}

\Xarrangement{paragraph}
\Xbeforeinserting{\LTR}
\Xlemmaseparator{[}%Will be reversed by Ezra SIL font
\Xafterlemmaseparator{0.5em}
\Xbeforelemmaseparator{0.25em}
\Xwrapcontent{\textenglish}
\Xwraplemma{\RL}

\newcommand{\ta}{\textarabic}

\linenumincrement{5}
\firstlinenum{5}

\title{The Epistle on Logic for Shams al-Dīn}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{Arabic}
\beginnumbering





\pstart
٢٢- وأمّا الثالث فإن امتنع انفكاكه عن معروضه فهو 
\edtext{اللازم}{\Afootnote{RT : \ta{العرضي اللازم} S.}}
 وإلّا فهو
\edtext{العرض المفارق}{\Afootnote{R : \ta{العرضي المفارق} ST.}}

\pend
\bigskip

\pstart
والعرضيّ
 المفارق إمّا سريع الزوال كحَمَرة الخجْل وصُفْرة الوَجَل، وإمّا بطيئه كالشيْب والشباب.
\pend  
\bigskip

\endnumbering

\end{Arabic}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not specialist at all of arabic use of reledmac. But maybe you could read http://geekographie.maieul.net/137. I will send also an email to someone who use everyday reledmac with arabic txt.

Comment: I tried to compile your mwe under lualatex with the help of `arabluatex` with some success. Sorry about this shameless bit of self-promotion though! Here it is (do not forget to use lualatex to compile this):

Answer (score 3):

This less an answer than an attempt at compiling your document under lualatex.  I will look into `xelatex` and `polyglossia` later, hopefully by the end of this week.

This works:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertineotf} 

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Amiri}
\usepackage{arabluatex}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english} 

\usepackage[noend,nofamiliar,noeledsec,series={A}]{reledmac}

\Xarrangement{paragraph}
%\Xbeforeinserting{\setLR}
\Xlemmaseparator{]}

\newcommand{\ta}{\txarb}

\linenumincrement{5} \firstlinenum{5}

\title{The Epistle on Logic for Shams al-Dīn} \date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\beginnumbering

\pstart[\setRL]
%
\begin{arab}
٢٢- وأمّا الثالث فإن امتنع انفكاكه عن معروضه فهو
\edtext{\arb{اللازم}}{\Afootnote{RT : \ta{العرضي اللازم} S.}} وإلّا فهو
\edtext{\arb{العرض المفارق}}{\Afootnote{R : \ta{العرضي المفارق} ST.}}
%
\end{arab}
\pend[\bigskip]

\pstart
\begin{arab}
%
 والعرضيّ المفارق إمّا سريع الزوال كحَمَرة الخجْل وصُفْرة الوَجَل، وإمّا بطيئه
 كالشيْب والشباب.
%
\end{arab}
\pend

\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! (I would have said thank-you yesterday, but I was out of town.) I'd love to see the xelatex solution too, if you get a chance.

Comment: I tried to make it work under XeLaTeX, but with no luck.  But I see you've moved to LuaLaTeX.  In my opinion, you did well ;)